# Coinmarketcap Get all coins with PHP

Tags: php, json, api

i am working on listing all coins information from coinmarketcap api https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?convert=USD&limit=1700 
i am facing problem of

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded.

```
$json_url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/? 
convert=USD&limit=1700";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
```

differnet

or i want suggestion , how can i import all data from api and post it to my webpage. Thanks

Comment: Have you taken the time to search what that error means and how to resolve it?

Comment: i am dividing my api call to sub calls , i am calling for 1st 200 coins and then onward , but it fails again after 500  coins.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Max execution time error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932855/max-execution-time-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not picky about execution times, you can always increase the execution time limit with [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) before executing your code, like so:

```
set_time_limit(300); // Sets timeout to 5 minutes (300 secs)
```

there is also the option to set to unlimited time by passing `0` as parameter but as always with infinity you should be very careful with that.

That being said, I think you should not integrate that like this into your page if it takes so long for you to load, and rather run this process asynchronously (e.g. with a Cronjob) or at least cache the data somewhere for some time.